# Run command one by one in cmd for Windows

Tags: windows, cmd

I want to do following:

1. Start a dotnet application in new process
2. Run some commands one by one, the next one should wait when previous finished/closed

So my cmd file looks like:

```
START /B dotnet "D:\myapp\MyApp.dll" # don't know how to open in new process/window

START "" RunACommand.exe -p -t # this must be started immediately after executing above command
START "" RunBCommand.exe # this must be executed after RunACommand has finished
START "" RunCCommand.exe # this must be executed after RunBCommand has finished
```

How to achieve ?

Comment: `start /?`. Look what `/B` does.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add /wait:

```
START /wait "" RunCCommand.exe # this must be executed after RunBCommand has 
finished
```